# How to use variable as a nested dictionary item name?

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

My script gets data from nested dictionary this way:

```
wx = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/blabla.json'))

wd = {}

if 'hourly' in wx:
  for item in wx['hourly']:
       wd['d1'] = str(wx['hourly']['data'][1]['temperature'])
       wd['d2'] = str(wx['hourly']['data'][2]['temperature'])
       wd['d3'] = str(wx['hourly']['data'][3]['temperature'])
       wd['d4'] = str(wx['hourly']['data'][4]['temperature'])
       # ...and 20 more...

print wd['d1'] + '° ' + wd['d2']  + '° ' # and more...
```

I want to reduce size of this code and create something like loop. But I can't mix string and variable. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
for item in range(24):
    wd["d{0}".format(item)] =  str(wx['hourly']['data']['{item}']['temperature'])
```

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre), it just need to write `[item]` instead of `['{item}']`.

Comment: not `['{item}']` just `[item]`. This is not a dict key.

Comment: also, bear in mind, `range(24)` will give you numbers 0-23, but in your example, you start with 1

Comment: I fail to see the problem. [repl.it](https://repl.it/HwWz/4)

Comment: What @Jean-FrançoisFabre said + the nature of `wd` lets me think it should possibly be a list.

Comment: list or other, `'{item}'` is just a string, not an integer.

Comment: You can still use `str(int_value)` and `int(str_value)`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a valid, working url for the JSON file being processed.

Comment: Hmm. It' works, thanks. I tried to use this previously, but got error. Can't undertand why this works now, but it works!

Comment: martineau, this is DarkSky json, it needs private API key: https://darksky.net/dev/docs/forecast
But the problem resolved, thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

Preserving the original code:

```
wx = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/blabla.json'))
wd = {}
if 'hourly' in wx:
    for item in wx['hourly']:
        wd['d'+str(i)] = str(wx['hourly']['data'][i]['temperature']) for i in range(1,25) #1st change

print '° '.join([wd['d'+str(i)] for i in range(1,25)]) #2nd change
```

And there you go!

~~~~

A little explanation:

In `#1st change`, I dynamically updated the values. `wd['d'+str(i)]` is the item in `wd` with key `'d' + str(i)`. Oh, and `['data'][i]` is basically `['data'][1]` on the first loop.

In `#2nd change`, I did a little one-liner to output all the items that you wanted, in the format you wanted. `[wd['d'+str(i)] for i in range(1,25)]` generates `[wd['d1'], wd['d2'], wd['d3'], ...]` as a list; then I `join()`ed the list with `'° '`, which is the separator you wanted.

Hope I helped!